Bash script reading from CSV seems to ignore variable values
I'm not a Bash expert, but I've followed Copilot examples, and the following should work, but it doesn't:
# CSV file contents
lineNo, column1, column2, column3, column4
1, true, true, true, abc
2, true, false, true, 123
3, false, true, false, xyz
0

Bash script:
while IFS=, read -r lineNo column1 column2 column3 column4
do
    echo $column4
     if [ "$column4" = "123" ]; then
        echo "condition is true"
     else
        echo "condition is false"
     fi
done < <(tail -n +2 $setupFileLocation)

However, my results are as follows:
abc
condition is false
123
condition is false
xyz
condition is false

Why are the actual variable values being ignored?  They are correct in the echo, but the IF...THEN isn't acknowledging the changing value. I've tested this with making the lineNo #1 the tested value, and it doens't make a difference.  All conditions return "false".
Why the trailing zero? If it isn't there the read Bash command only returns the header and first two rows.  I haven't figured this out yet, but it's a different subject.
Are there any wonderful Bash SMEs out there who can assist?

Use [tag:nash] loadable csv: see my answer

Or whipe unwanted spaces by if [[ ${column4// } == 123 ]]; then ... (prefer double braces...)

The problem is the spaces after the commas; that's not part of the CSV format, and the the spaces are being treated as part of the column value. echo $column4 doesn't show this because the variable reference isn't double-quoted (variable references should almost always be double-quoted). See "I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else" and "When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"

@GordonDavisson, Thank you.  You are correct.  This is what happens when you try to make a source file by hand.  I appreciate your feedback.
